# Create and run an application on pandaboard using Qt

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, yocto, pandaboard

I am looking to create an application using Qt on an x86 Ubuntu Dist, and I want to create the application for an ARM7 Pandaboard.  I have been in contact with the technical staff at Qt, which were a great help with the initial installation and setup of Qt on the Linux x86 computer.

I can currently create an `exe` through QtCreator using the Yacto toolchain.

The Qt Tech explained that the `exe` was created using GCC 4.6 and should work on Pandaboard running Yocto based image.

If I move that file directly to the pandaboard which is running Ubuntu 12.4 and attempt to run it, I receive the error: `No Command Found`

I am now quite certain that I need to install Yacto on the pandaboard.
I tried to follow the instructions listed:

"http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.3/poky-ref-manual/poky-ref-manual.html#ref-images"
and
"http://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/pandayocto/"

Failure occurs here: `time bitbake -c fetchall core-image-sato`
or 
`bitbake care-image-sato`

Usual error(s) include:

> Unable to determine endianness for architecture 'armv7l'
>   Please add your architecture to siteinfo.bbclass
>   and quite a few others

My Root Question

1. Am I even going down the right path for running a Qt application on a pandaboard?
2. Which version of yocto do I need?

   - I downloaded and tried the following:

     - [Link 1](http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-1.3/poky-danny-8.0.tar.bz2)
     - [Link 2](http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-1.2/poky-denzil-7.0.tar.bz2)
3. Is there a working set of instructions to complete this installation? (I am new to Linux)
4. Does anyone know how to distribute and run an application from an x86 Linux machine onto a connected pandaboard as shown in this video of a Qt developer doing so?
   [Youtube link](http://youtu.be/lp7zRsw9_2s)

Any help someone can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I know this is possible, but it seems there are a few issues that need to be solved first.

Comment: This seems more of a yocto question than a Qt one. Qt should run on any of the Linux distributions installable on the Pandaboard, unless the distro is so minimalistic that something crucial from the stack is missing.